# DataGridView sorting by date: preserve order entered in if same date

Tags: vb.net, sorting, date, datagridview

I have a DGV that on a button click I call on DGV.sort, with the DGV set to Auto sort. The column being sorted is a date column. When the dates are the same it tends to mix up the order that I entered them in, which is the opposite of what I want it to do. Example:

> 1/2/15  Bear
>   1/1/15  Cat
>   1/1/15  Dog
>   1/1/15  Lizard

call the sort func., current results:

> 1/1/15  Dog
>   1/1/15  Lizard
>   1/1/15  Cat
>   1/2/15  Bear

What I want to do is preserve the order if the dates are the same, like so:

> 1/1/15  Cat
>   1/1/15  Dog
>   1/1/15  Lizard
>   1/2/15  Bear

any help would be great!

Comment: "The column being sorted is a date column." Are you sure it isn't being sorted as a string? What's the column type?

Comment: And if you want to do a custom sorting, you may want to look into create a custom IComparer.

Comment: The type is "DataGridViewTextBoxColumn", with a DefaultCellStyle = {Format = MM/dd/yy}. I've been looking into the custom IComparer but I would like to avoid that if I can.

Comment: You're still a type of "textbox column", which means it will default to sorting as a string. You also have these extra values after your date (cat/dog/etc) which is messing you up (unless they're in a separate column, but it doesn't look like it here). I suggest adding this column as a column of the Date type. That avoids custom comparison.